# How do you create a custom back navigation in Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

I am trying to implement a custom navigation in my Flutter app.

From my main page I have the following routes possible:

**Option 1**

Main --> dashboard --> user deal list --> deal page --> detail page

**Option 2**

Main --> login --> dashboard --> user deal list --> deal page --> detail page

The issue I have in option 1 is that when wanting to navigate in option 1 from detail page backwards I want to be able to go to the deal page but the navigation takes me back to Main.

In option 2 after logging in, when on the dashboard, the user should be going to the Main page and not back to the login page.

I have tried using WillPopScope as follows:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return WillPopScope(
    onWillPop: () async {

       Navigator.pop(context,  MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BuyerDealPage()),);
       return false;
   },
   child: MaterialApp(

     home: Scaffold(
```

But with the above, the app still navigates all the way back to the Main page instead of going back to the deal page.

I tried moving the `WillPopScope` below Material app, that doesn’t work either.

Am I using `WillPopScope` incorrectly? I though the idea was that `WillPopScope` overrides the back button?

I have tried replacing `Navigator.pop` with `Navigator.push` as well and that doesn’t seem to work either.

Not sure if it helps at all but I have implemented `WillPopScope` on all my pages as I wanted to ensure that I specify the back navigation.

Edit: my code on how i am pushing between pages (example for user deal list --> deal page)

```
Navigator.push(context,MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => BuyerDealPage()));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think just a standard `Navigator.of(context).pop()` should work in your case if you push next pages using `Navigator.of(context).push()` or `Navigator.of(context).pushNamed()`.

For the second scenario, when you push dashboard page after logging in, you can use `Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement()` method, which will replace login page with dashboard page. This way, when you try to go back from dashboard page, you will go directly to Main page.

If you want to achieve the same behavior with Android back button, you need to wrap your page with `WillPopScope` just as you did, but in `onWillPop` use:

```
WillPopScope(
   onWillPop: () async {
       Navigator.of(context).pop();
       return false;
   },
   child: ...yourNextWidgetHere...
```

Comment: am I meant to keep the brackets empty? Or am I supposed to insert a widget into it?

Comment: You should only keep brackets empty for `pop`. For the other ones you need to pass appropriate parameter, either route name for `pushNamed` or whole Route object for `push` and `pushReplacement`

Comment: Doesn't work. still jumps to Main, after I press the back button when on the detail page.

Comment: Could you share some code on how you push new pages? And what do you mean by back button? The android system back button, or the button in top left corner of the app?

Comment: Android back button. app bar back button works ok. I have edited my code with a code snippet.

Comment: I edited my post aswell. Could you try the code inside it?

Comment: after lots of investigation, it seems the reason this was not working for me is because I added MaterialApp to each of the new pages. This is not meant to happen and is only supposed to be added to the First page. I will be testing in detail a little later and will accept you answer once I am sure the `pushreplacement` works.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up reworking my navigation by implementing named routes. i then used `pushNamedreplacement` in all places where navigation needed to occur. this includes in `WillPopScope`. do not use `pop.context` instead, use `pushnamedreplacement`.

Also, being new to Flutter, i added MaterialApp to each new widget which you should NOT DO.

this causes confusion in the navigation.